# How do I properly re-send a process to background after fg in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-terminal

In my remote terminal I have put in background the following running Linux process

`dd if=/dev/sda3 | gzip -1 - | pv | ssh user@.rsync.net dd of=image.gz`in

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- `bg`
- `disown pid1 pid2 pid3 pid4` (4 `pids` since they are 4 commands in sequence where each pipes to the next one)

Then (without having left current SSH terminal session yet) I brought it in foreground with `fg` and I see it running.

---

**1.** How do I exit `fg` and send the process (job) back to its background ?

I am afraid that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will make a second
background or job for the already backgrounded process or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will end both `fg` screen and the process itself.

**2.** Also would it be possible to run `fg` for the same `job` again and bring it to foreground if I disconnect from remote terminal and reopen it after a while?

Comment: You `disown` it and then you're able to `fg`? What shell is it?

Comment: Yes I can `fg` it because I haven't still disconnected from the very same SSH session where I started the `bg` of the process. Second question has to do with that. | `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Strange. This is very different from Bash 4.3.48 and what I know about jobs. I `disown` a whole job (even if giving just one PID that belongs to the pipe of the job). After that it's no longer on the job list, so I cannot `fg` it. Your experience is different so there must be something I don't know.